# Makefile and Files under a directory

Tags: makefile

I have Makefile under a directory and directory has many .pm ( perl files )
I want to add makefile at this directory level which does perl file syntax checking.
Basically I want to add:

```
perl -c <filename>
```

How to get list of files automatically in that directory without hardcoding.

Comment: If you find an answer that works for you, it is customary to accept that answer (with the tick mark that appears under it when you look at the answers; it goes green when you choose it).

Comment: Having said which, I see that 'Avinash' asked the question but a different 'Avinash' said "this works for me".

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me in the GNU makefile (Linux and Windows)

```
ALL_PM_FILES = $(wildcard *.pm)
```

Then run a for/foreach loop on them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the filter command:

```
PMFILES=$(filter %.pm, $(SRC))
```

Documentation for filter is hard to find. See [here](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2002/02/14/makefiles.html?page=2) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal workaround:

```
check_pm_syntax:
        for file in *.pm; do ${PERL} -c $$file; done
```

You run '`make check_pm_syntax`' and it goes off and runs the shell loop for all the `*.pm` files it can find.  You can simply list `check_pm_syntax` as a pre-requisite for your `all` target if you like (but it means you'll always do work when you build `all`).  The only time this causes trouble is if there are no `*.pm` files in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
.PHONY: check_%.pm
check_%.pm:
    perl -c $*.pm

check_all: $(addprefix check_,$(wildcard *.pm))
```